# Leverage browser caching is not working at all

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have the following code in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I do inspect element in Google chrome: The js and css are NOT loading from chach instead they are loading fresh every time.

please help anyone?

Comment: There are many things that could be causing this. Is your server using Apache or nginx? If it's using Apache, is the `mod_expires` module enabled? Have you got the 'Disable cache' checkbox checked on the Network tab within Chrome dev tools?

Comment: yes I did Enabled mod_expires and 'Disable cache' checkbox NOT checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your expires module is enabled:

```
# apachectl -M |grep 'expires'
expires_module (shared)
Syntax OK
#
```

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: Please post example response headers for one asset e.g. some jpg image.